# Easy way to display geometric objects

Tags: java, geometry, display

I am developing a java application that allows me to calculate distances on a carpentry drawing. The program uses different geometric objects such as segments, points, lines...etc and I would like to find a simple way to display these objects. I thought of 2 solutions:

Write an image or write a geogebra file. But I don't know how to apply one of these solutions in a simple way....

So if you have any advice, tools, solutions to recommend to me I will be very grateful!

Comment: If you want to display some geometric shapes, give JavaFX2 a go. It's simple and you can both display the images during the program execution and download them as files.

Comment: I already use javafx for the user interface of my program, but I'm not sure I understand your proposal, if I understood correctly you tell me that it's possible to write in an image with javafx? So I could for example draw lines, display points, draw rectangles... etc?